# Finding voltage thevenin

Tags: voltage, thevenin

[image: Circuit Image]

[image: Annotated Circuit Image]

I calculated R thevenin to be 5.322 ohms, but I don't know how to get a voltage after this step. I tried to use node voltage equations since V thevenin is he voltage across the terminals, but it didn't work out... I had:

va-vb=-I1[the current in the loop with V source, clockwise]*8ohms +55V=59.4V

I1 was gotten from mesh current analysis and I1=-.55

[image]

Comment: Please annotate your circuit to include circuit references and mark your currents I1etc any voltages you think relevant V1 etc. It make it much easier for us  to help

Comment: Is that better? I think I annotated all stuff needed for node voltage and mesh current.

Comment: Much thanks. Normally it is also good to label your components R1, R2 etc but since every current loop is labelled and we have all component values it is not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert current sources to voltage sources and we'll get a simpler circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw2cIY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using nodal law at **A**,

$$\frac{V_A}{18} + \frac{(V_A-16)}{22} + \frac{(V_A-199)}{14} = 0$$

On solving, we will get \$V_A = 86.65 V\$

So the current through R1 and R9: 
$$I = (V_A - 199)/14 = -8.025 A$$

Note the minus sign. The direction of **I** is therefore from ground to the node A, through R9 and R1.

let us find \$V_B\$:
$$V_B = 144  - IR_9 = 144 - 48.15 = 95.85 V$$

Therefore the thevenins voltage \$V_{AB} \$ will be:
$$ V_{AB} = V_A - V_B = -9.2V$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't using this approach when applying the node voltage method. I forgot that I had to account for all the currents leaving node A. I appreciate the diagram and everything.

Comment: :-) you are welcome. You can also solve this quickly using loop currents method.

Answer (score 0):

If you work backwards from the 8 ohm resistor loop on the far right - calculate the voltage drop of each one of those three, then you have the voltage across the 18 ohm resistor. Calculate its current, then you have the current through the 8 ohm resistor and you can calculate its voltage drop to get the voltage at terminal A

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it helps to define a local 0V and arbitrarily I have chosen \$V_b\$ for this. Now lets label our other nodes \$V_c\$ is the top of the 2A current source (between the 10 \$\Omega\$ and 8 \$\Omega\$ resistor). \$V_d\$ is the bottom of the 2A current source (between the 8 \$\Omega\$ and 4 \$\Omega\$ resistor). \$V_e\$ is the junction between the 6 \$\Omega\$, the 18 \$\Omega\$ and 4 \$\Omega\$ resistor.

It is basically an arithmetic slog to find out what you can from a bunch of simultaneous equations.  We have

\$I_4 - I_2 = 2 \text{A}\$

\$I_3 = 24 \text{A}\$

\$V_c - V_d = I_4 \cdot 8 \Omega \$

\$55\text{V} = I_1 \cdot 8 \Omega + (I_1 - I_2) \cdot 18 \Omega + (I_1 - I_3) \cdot 6 \Omega \$

\$ I_2 = \dfrac{V_a - V_c}{10 \Omega} = \dfrac{V_d - V_e}{4 \Omega}\$

\$ V_a = (I_1 -I_2) \cdot 18 \Omega + (I_1 -I_3) \cdot 6 \Omega\$

The Thevenin voltage \$ V_{th} \$ is **just** \$ V_a \$.  It will drop out of these equations if you are methodical eliminating one variable at a time.

Alternatively you can use Thevenin several times to simplify the circuit.

You could just start by considering just the right hand \$ 8 \Omega \$ resistor and 2A source what is its Thevenin equivalent?

Redraw the circuit. The \$ 10 \Omega \$ and \$4 \Omega \$ resistors can now be considered to be in series in the new circuit. What does that do?

You may need to simplify a few more times.

Post your efforts as part of your answer if you get stuck and we will assist further.  If you manage to solve it post an answer and send me a comment so I know and I will up vote you.